# Restore inner HTML after javascript mutations

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

For a website, I do heavy modifications to the inner HTML using javascript, when the window outer width drops below 768px. I change div ids, move ul elements, inject HTML using Ajax, and many other mutations.

I know this is not best practice, should be mobile first, but it is too late for this now.

My question. Any chance to magically restore my inner HTML when the window is resized back to larger than 768px? So that I can make the website feel really responsive? Without refreshing the page (some page content is dinamically generated).

So far tried this:

1. Save the inner HTML to seession storage `sessionStorage['thispage'] = document.querySelector('html').innerHTML;` then get it back when the window is larger than 768px `document.querySelector('html').innerHTML = sessionStorage['thispage'];` - Best results so far, but still inconsistent.
2. Load the entire original inner HTML into the document using Ajax

   $(document).ready(function() {

   $.ajax({
    type:'post',
    data:{},
    url:document.url,
    dataType:'html',
    success:function(response){
      $('body').html(response);
    }
   });

   });

Not great, equivalent to a refresh.

Any other ideas please? Do I really have to reverse-engineer the javascript code so that I add an "undo" to the changes?

Comment: Whatever you're trying to do, its a VERY bad idea to store the entire HTML of a page in a JS var and then inject it back onto the page when the dimensions change.

Comment: what are the issues when you use sessionStorage to put the page back? All I can think of is that you modify the css with javascript which would not be restored with innerHTML? Do you add any styles to the container itself.

Comment: You can try [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp). CSS media-rule, It can make your site responsive. It is also lighter than using JS.

Comment: @Ekim - If I inject HTML in the original page, when reverting back to the version in the session storage I get some artifacts. Still looking into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are stuck with this (which is horrible), why don't you just give each html 'version' a container, like a div, and show/hide based on the size? You can maintain a variable that indicates whether the async-loaded content has already been loaded, so you just have to show it instead of re-loading.

Best idea is to re-do of course.

Comment: DvS can you please elaborate a little on this? Are you suggesting that in the page source I should write two versions of the html - one for desktop and one for mobile? And no longer use javascript to change the HTML?

Comment: I think you should load the mobile version by default, then load the desktop version when you reach your width breakpoint. Bear in mind that this may be on page load, if the client is using a larger viewport.